# How to set multiple HttpContext.Session.SetObjectAsJson

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a controller with multiple Views and multiple Models, In fact it is a registration steps, that each View has it's own model...
I want to save models in DB **after ending registration steps.**
I used `HttpContext.Session.Set` in every `IActionResult` but only Last session has Value

This is my code:

```
public class RegisterController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Step1(Model1 myModel)
    {    
        HttpContext.Session.SetObjectAsJson("Step1", myModel);
    
        return RedirectToAction("Step2");     
    }

    public IActionResult Step2(Model2 myModel)
    {     
        HttpContext.Session.SetObjectAsJson("Step2", myModel);
    
        return RedirectToAction("Step3");     
    }

    public IActionResult Step3(Model3 myModel)
    {            
         HttpContext.Session.SetObjectAsJson("Step3", myModel);
    
         return RedirectToAction("Step4");     
    }
    

    public ViewResult Step4()
    {
        var Model1Value = HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<Model1>("Step1");
        var Model2Value = HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<Model2>("Step2");
        var Model3Value = HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<Model3>("Step3");
    }
}
```

but `Model1Value` and `Model2Value` are null and 3rd one has value.

what should I do for saving Models Value??

Answer (score 0):

> I used HttpContext.Session.Set in every IActionResult but only Last session has Value

I did a test with following code snippet, which works well.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{

    return RedirectToAction("Step1",new { M1Name = "testm1"});
            
    //return View();
}

public IActionResult Step1(Model1 myModel)
{
    HttpContext.Session.SetObjectAsJson("Step1", myModel);

    return RedirectToAction("Step2", new { M2Name = "testm2" });
}

public IActionResult Step2(Model2 myModel)
{
    HttpContext.Session.SetObjectAsJson("Step2", myModel);

    return RedirectToAction("Step3", new { M3Name = "testm3" });
}

public IActionResult Step3(Model3 myModel)
{
    HttpContext.Session.SetObjectAsJson("Step3", myModel);

    return RedirectToAction("Step4");
}


public ViewResult Step4()
{
    var Model1Value = HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<Model1>("Step1");
    var Model2Value = HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<Model2>("Step2");
    var Model3Value = HttpContext.Session.GetObjectFromJson<Model3>("Step3");
    //...
```

Model classes

```
public class Model3
{
    public string M3Name { get; set; }
}

public class Model2
{
    public string M2Name { get; set; }
}

public class Model1
{
    public string M1Name { get; set; }
}
```

Test Result

[image]

Please debug the code and check the actual value of `myModel` while you set Session value in action method.

Besides, `RedirectToAction` method is used to redirect to specified action instead of rendering the HTML, you call this method between multi `Step(s)` action methods without showing registration page for each registration step, which seems not common way of implementing registration steps functionality.